# JQuery show div based on value in another div

Tags: jquery

I have a list of products, where each product has a number inside one div. Based on this number i need to show another div. This doesn't work at all.

JS

```
if ($('.producerId').html() == 1) {
$(".one").show();
}
if ($('.producerId').html() == 2) {
$(".two").show();
}
if ($('.producerId').html() == 3) {
$(".three").show();
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="producerId">2</div>
<div class="producerImage">
<div class="one">one</div>
<div class="two">two</div>
<div class="two">three</div>
</div>
<div class="producerId">1</div>
<div class="producerImage">
<div class="one">one</div>
<div class="two">two</div>
<div class="two">three</div>
</div>
<div class="producerId">3</div>
<div class="producerImage">
<div class="one">one</div>
<div class="two">two</div>
<div class="two">three</div>
</div>
```

[Here's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teva/4jt2v0dp/)

Comment: your classes are ambiguous.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4jt2v0dp/3/

Comment: Tnx Learner...works!

Answer (score 2):

You need to hide the classes `.one`, `.two` and `.three` instead of its parent `div` `.producerImage` and you can do it using `switch case` with `$.each` looping all the `div`'s with class `producerId` as below:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/4jt2v0dp/4/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each($('.producerId'),function(){
       var value=$(this).html();
       var that=$(this);
       switch(value)
       {
           case "1":
                   that.next().find($('.one')).show();
               break;
           case "2":
                   that.next().find($(".two")).show();
               break;
           case "3":
                   that.next().find($(".three")).show();
               break;
           default:
               break;

       }
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.one,.two,.three {
    display:none;
}
```

There are 2 `divs` `two` and `three` with identical classes. You have given `two` for both:

**Updated `html`**

```
<div class="producerId">2</div>
<div class="producerImage">
    <div class="one">one</div>
    <div class="two">two</div>
    <div class="three">three</div>
</div>
<div class="producerId">1</div>
<div class="producerImage">
    <div class="one">one</div>
    <div class="two">two</div>
    <div class="three">three</div>
</div>
<div class="producerId">3</div>
<div class="producerImage">
    <div class="one">one</div>
    <div class="two">two</div>
    <div class="three">three</div>
</div>
```